# Docker: git add <filename> like feature

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Suppose I have 10 files changes in my existing docker image. How would I commit only 2 specific files and create a separate tag?

Something Like:

```
docker commit -m file1 file2
```

**Edited:** see my request has been closed by docker members. 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20897

Comment: docker commit is for images not files

Comment: make sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, `man docker commit` <del>tells you why</del> does not offer this operation.

---

#### Edit

It just that the command does not offer this operation and usually the man page does not details what and why the tool does not offer. Nevertheless, my guess is: it is programmatically possible to perform this operation but may lead in inconsistent images, or incoherent, and might be dangerous. Let's say you installed a package, and want to commit these files but forget a conf-file (or anything else) the image would be in a *weird-not-so-clean* state. Also, using `docker commit` is far away from the best practice to create image. Prefer a `Dockerfile` which make image lighter to build

Comment: I read that manual page and did not find the actual reason. Can you help me understand ?

Comment: I can't really explain more actually. _see the edit as the comment is too long otherwise_.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the contents of a container, you can use the `docker commit` command to save the current state of the container as a new tag.

```
$ docker commit <CONTAINER_ID> <IMAGE_NAME>:<NEW_TAG>
```

Comment: My question is to commit the selective files among the changes.

Comment: @BhuwanGautam I know this is not a direct answer to the question, but it could be a workaround since the `docker commit` is not designed to commit files. I have updated my answer for clarification.